# Included PHP class doesn't know config.php

Tags: php, config

this one left me quite confused, so maybe someone here can help.

I developed a website using Netbeans and XAMPP on my local system, where it runs perfectly. Now I tried to move this to the webspace to let others take a look. Shouldn't be a problem since I put the database connection info and all paths in a config.php which would only need a few changes, or so I thought.

The **index.php** only includes the config, then includes a helper class and creates the object that should do all the work.

```
require_once('config.php'); 
require_once(LIB_PATH.'system/RequestController.class.php');
new RequestController();
```

Works well locally, but the page stays white on the webspace. So far I only figured out, that the RequestController class does not know anything about the config.php. So when the **RequestController.class.php** tries to include something else ...

```
require_once(LIB_PATH.'system/SessionController.class.php');
```

... everything falls apart since it doesn't know the constant LIB_PATH.

Any idea what I can do short of adding the config include to every single class? Why does it work locally but not on the webspace, even though nothing else has changed?

I'm thankful for any input!

Comment: Start by examining your error logs, output logs, browser console log, etcetera, so you would know what's really happening...

Comment: Check that where you define `LIB_PATH` variable there you gave localhost somewhere. that's why it is not working on server. Or add `config.php` file into second `php page` also.thanks.

Comment: The error log isn't of much help, only tells me: [Sun Jun 07 20:43:52 2015] [error] [client ...] PHP Fatal error:  require_once() [[a href='function.require']function.require[/a]]: Failed opening required '[...]/RequestController.class.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear/php5.3') in [...]/index.php on line 5

Comment: Post your config.php, but please make sure to redact usernames/passwords... anything thats sensitive.

Comment: @prodigitalson: http://jpst.it/zouo

Comment: So is the `[...]` part of the error message for the `RequestController` correct?

Comment: Yes, it's the correct path to the RequestController class

Comment: A new error popped up: In RequestController the line "require_once(LIB_PATH.'system/SessionController.class.php');" leads to "PHP Fatal error:  require_once() [[a href='function.require']function.require[/a]]: Failed opening required 'LIB_PATHsystem/SessionController.class.php'"

So my guess is that since the config isnt known, it doesnt know the constant LIB_PATH and just interprets it as a string.

Answer (score 0):

What I think that problem is with your naming, as on localhost your are working fine, check out each of your class names, etc. as name as case sensitive on Linux server.